# passing url parameters in chrome headless are not working with selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, url, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

Please suggest some approach on passing url parameters with Chrome Headless using Selenium- Java

I am passing url parameters as below while launching url and those values are passed correctly and the UI renders as per the values passed in url - while executing in Chrome without headless

URL example : {domain}/?**ref=pd_sl_5szpgfto9i_e**

While executing same script in Chrome headless the url parameters are passed but the UI is not rendered as per the parameters passed in URL
{domain}/?**ref=pd_sl_5szpgfto9i_e**

based on ?**ref=pd_sl_5szpgfto9i_e** this parameter the UI working should change to other view

Answer (score 0):

Headless mode has different reaction times. Make sure that your problem is not related to this, i.e. if your website is rendering the content before you want to interact with it. If not, then add some waiting. For quick checking, you can add `Thread.sleep(2000)` after the `get()` method and before checking the `WebElement`, but do not leave it in the final version of your tests and rather use the class `WebDriverWait` instead.

If this does not solve your problem, then try to check your code on some other page and provide a minimal example, for example:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
                .addArguments("--headless");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow");
        if (driver
                .findElements(new By.ByPartialLinkText("Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn"))
                .isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Not found results of query passed in the URL");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Argument was passed in the URL correctly");
        }
        driver.quit();
    }
```

The correct output is:

```
Argument was passed in the URL correctly
```